# Joomla - How to hide Version update option from admin dashboard

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I want to hide Version update option from admin dashboard in joomla 2.5.6.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a plugin that you need to disable-

go to `plugins->Quick Icon - Joomla! Update Notification`

[image]

Comment: You an also use access control so that only some users see the button.

Comment: I use joomla for years now and I seriously didn't know there was a plugin for this, lol

Answer (score 5):

go to

plugins->   Quick Icon - Joomla! Extensions Updates Notification

plugins->   Quick Icon - Joomla! Update Notification

Disable plugin.